# Script code executing before html is rendered on the page. Only happens in the Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Hi all first time posting a question here. I usually find the answer to my problems here, but couldn't this time. I have a very simply to do list web app that just involves some plain html (which is the instructions) and the script. Whenever I open this page in chrome the script executes, but no html loads until after I quit the script. I have tried implementing inline scripts, aysnc, and defer but those do not seem to help. If I load the page with Mozilla however, the app functions just fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>To Do List</title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>To Do List!</h1>
    <br>
    <ul>
      <li><i>list</i>- check your todo list</li>
      <li><i>add</i>- add an item onto your todo list</li>
      <li><i>remove</i>- deleve an item off of your todo list</li>
      <li><i>quit</i>- exit the app</li>
    </ul>
     <script src= "script.js" > </script>
  </body>
</html>


script.js 

    var todolist=["get a dog"];
    alert("hello");
    var input= prompt("What would you like to do?");


    while (input !== "quit") {
      if (input=== "list") {
        console.log("*******");
        todolist.forEach( function(x,i) {
          console.log((i+1) + ": " + x)
        })
        console.log("*******");
      }
      else if (input === "add") {
        var addition= prompt("What item would you like to add to your todo list?")
        todolist.push(addition);
      }
      else if (input === "remove") {
        var i = prompt("Enter the number of the list item to be removed");
        todolist.splice(i-1, 1);
      }
      input= prompt("What would you like to do?")
    }

    console.log("You have exited the app");
```

Comment: your page will show up after you exit the loop and reach the end of the script.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a beginners attempt to write a fully browser console based application and was solved in a way that is very unlikely to help any future visitor.